# Capture the output of an external program in JAVA

Tags: java, exec, output

I'm trying to capture output of an external program using java but I can't.

I have the code to show it, but not to put it into a variable.

I will use, for example, sqlplus to execute my oracle code  "into exec.sql"
system/orcl@orcl : user/password/DB name

```
public static String test_script () {
        String RESULT="";
        String fileName = "@src\\exec.sql";
        String sqlPath = ".";
        String arg1="system/orcl@orcl";
        String sqlCmd = "sqlplus";


        String arg2   = fileName;
        try {
            String line;
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(sqlCmd, arg1, arg2);
            Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
            env.put("VAR1", arg1);
            env.put("VAR2", arg2);
            pb.directory(new File(sqlPath));
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process p = pb.start();
          BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

          while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {

              RESULT+=line;

          }


          System.out.println("Done.");
        }
        catch (Exception err) {
          err.printStackTrace();
        }
 return RESULT;
    }
```

Comment: What you are asking is not clear. You can see it with `System.out.println(line);`, but `RESULT` is empty?

Comment: RESULT is empty at the beginning but in the while loop I made ​​the concatenation --> RESULT+=line;

Comment: ok but can you see the lines printed with `System.out.println(line);`? Also note that because you have redirected the error stream, you don't need `bre` - everything will be streamed to `bri`.

Comment: Shouldn´t you read from the outputstream of the external program? p.getOutputStream()

Comment: I corrected the mistakes

Comment: There nothing obviously wrong with your code. Are you sure that the command outputs something?

Comment: @HectorLector No he is doing it correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the Process will execute in a new thread it's likely that there is no output or incomplete output available when you come to your while loop.

```
Process p = pb.start();  
// process runs in another thread parallel to this one

BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

// bri may be empty or incomplete.
while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
    RESULT+=line;
}
```

So you need to wait for the process to complete before attempting to interact with it's output. Try using the [Process.waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) method to pause the current thread until your process has had an opportunity to complete.

```
Process p = pb.start();  
p.waitFor();  // wait for process to finish then continue.

BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
    RESULT+=line;
}
```

This is only a simple approach you could also process the output of the process while it runs in parallel but then you would need to monitor the status of the process i.e. is it still running or has it completed, and the availability of output.

Answer (score 7):

Use [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/), it will make your life much easier. Check the [tutorials](http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html) for information about basic usage. To read the command line output after obtaining an `executor` object (probably `DefaultExecutor`), create an `OutputStream` to whatever stream you wish (i.e a `FileOutputStream` instance may be, or `System.out`), and:

```
executor.setStreamHandler(new PumpStreamHandler(yourOutputStream));
```

Comment: It's a java library. Trust me, it will save you a LOT of effort. If you face ANY trouble with, post it right here and I will be glad to help you, anytime :)

Comment: 10xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx I'm gonna test it now :D

Comment: @AHmédNet, that's great to know brother :) It will save you a lot of trouble inshaa Allah

Comment: I'm confused - does it write both stdout and stderr to the same pump stream handler?

Comment: ah yes, has multiple args.